# in the client configuration, it says that I don't have a configuration with the name xxx

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have this configuration in my app config in the client application:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="netHttpBinding_ICalculadora" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="Deflate" />
          <tcpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFCalculadoraService/Service1/"
          binding="netHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netHttpBinding_ICalculadora"
          contract="WCFCalculadoraService.ICalculadoraService" name="NetHttpBinding_ICalculadoraService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But I get an error that says that I don't have a configuration with the name "netHttpBinding_ICalculadora", but I have a custom binding configuration with this name. Why do I get this error?

Thank so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is the problem -

set 
    binding="customBinding" instead of binding="netHttpBinding"